# How to convert a date from a different timezone to UTC in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime, timezone, utc

I have a datetime in format:

```
5/20/2011 12:00:00 AM
```

Even though it is not mentioned in date, I am aware that this date is in CST Timezone (America/Chicago).
How do I convert this to UTC time?

I would prefer not to add/subtract time but instead use an existing php function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the datetime object for that purpose.

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP');

$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to set default timezone

```
date_default_timezone_set


<?php
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); // To set UTC time


?>
```